# after installing flask_mysqldb, python shell show the same error

Tags: python-3.x

Error as shown in the Python Shell:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/Saabia/Desktop/Puraa/pypy.py", line 2, in <module>
        from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_mysqldb'
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to install it first.

```
pip install Flask-MySQLdb
```

and see if any errors occur

Comment: Can you not see that the author has a Windows? Please correct your ansers for that.